# Typescript Module + Webpack + RequireJS

Tags: typescript, webpack, requirejs

Working on my first typescript module, which I hope to be able to use in both an Apache Cordova app, and a .Net 4.6 MVC site (for now). After doing exhaustive reading I came to the conclusion that CommonJS would suit my needs best. However I'm struggling to integrate the module into the MVC site.

I'm using webpack with awesome-typescript-loader to bundle my module into a single js file, and then I am using requirejs to load the module onto the MVC site. I have attempted multiple ways to import the module with no success.

Within my typescript module I have a single point of entry (index.ts), in which I am ONLY exporting the main class: `export * from './src/engine';`, and I am using this class as my entry point within webpack:

```
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const merge = require('webpack-merge');
const CheckerPlugin = require('awesome-typescript-loader').CheckerPlugin;

module.exports = (env) => {
    // Configuration in common to both client-side and server-side bundles
    const isDevBuild = false;
    const sharedConfig = {
        stats: { modules: false },
        context: __dirname,
        resolve: { extensions: ['.ts', '.tsx'] },
        output: {
            filename: '[name].js',
            publicPath: '/dist/' // Webpack dev middleware, if enabled, handles requests for this URL prefix
        },
        module: {
            loaders: [
                {
                    test: /\.tsx?$/,
                    loader: 'awesome-typescript-loader'
                }
            ]
        },
        plugins: [
            new CheckerPlugin()
        ]
    };

    // Configuration for client-side bundle suitable for running in browsers
    const clientBundleOutputDir = './dist';
    const clientBundleConfig = merge(sharedConfig, {
        entry: { 'engine': './index.ts' },
        output: { path: path.join(__dirname, clientBundleOutputDir) },
        plugins: [
            new webpack.ContextReplacementPlugin(/moment[\\\/]locale$/, /^\.\/(en)$/)
        ].concat(isDevBuild ? [
            // Plugins that apply in development builds only
            new webpack.SourceMapDevToolPlugin({
                filename: '[file].map', // Remove this line if you prefer inline source maps
                moduleFilenameTemplate: path.relative(clientBundleOutputDir, '[resourcePath]') // Point sourcemap entries to the original file locations on disk
            })
        ] : [
                // Plugins that apply in production builds only
                new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin()
            ])
    });

    return [clientBundleConfig];
};
```

Once I have the resultant engine.js file I am using requirejs on the MVC site to load the module:

`<script data-main="/scripts/main" src="~/Scripts/require.js"></script>`

main.js

```
require(['/scripts/compliance-engine.js']);
```

With the final aim being that I can call `var compliance = require('compliance-engine');` from javascript, instantiating a new instance of the engine.

Sadly no matter what I try I am unable to get the above working to completion (no errors are thrown at any point, I just can't reference the module on the site).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using `webpack` NOTHING is exported unless you explicitly define it, you should add this to your webpack.config.js

```
output: {
 library: 'MyLibrary'
 libraryTarget: 'var',
}
```

This will put a variable named `MyLibrary` on the window and it can be accessed from your other code.
There are other options to `libraryTarget` like `umd`/`amd` etc.
you can read about it [here](https://survivejs.com/webpack/output/library-output/)

Comment: You sir are a god, that was exactly the problem! Thank you so much